# Ember.Select - can't pre-select an option before displaying control

Tags: ember.js, ember.select

I'm sure this is dead simple, but I'm enough of a newbie at both JS and Ember to be stumped for two days now.  The initial value is coming from the API as model.status (int).
But my init() code does not cause the select control to show that item.  Why not?  And if there is a much better way to do this, please let me know.  Thanks in advance!

Here's my HTML:

```
{{view Ember.Select id='selectUserStatus'  
  content=selectUserStatus  
  optionValuePath="content.val"
  optionLabelPath="content.label"
  value=status
  selectionBinding="selectedUserStatus"
  prompt="Select a status"}}
```

Here's the JS:

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

init: function() {
  var selVal = this.get('model.status');
  this.set('selectedUserStatus',[this.get('selectUserStatus')[selVal-1]]);
},

selectUserStatus: [
   {label:"Guest", val:"1"},
   {label:"Registered",val:"2"}, 
   {label:"Editor",val:"3"}, 
   {label:"Administrator",val:"4"},
],
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best if you could provide a jsFiddle or jsBin. However from looking at your code I would suggest the following:

```
{{view Ember.Select id='selectUserStatus'  
  content=userStatusList  
  optionValuePath="content.val"
  optionLabelPath="content.label"
  value=status
  selectionBinding="selectedUserStatus"
  prompt="Select a status"}}
```

Here's the JS:

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  init: function() {
    var selVal = this.get('model.status');
    this.set('selectedUserStatus',[this.get('selectUserStatus')[selVal-1]]);
  },

  userStatusList: [
    {label:"Guest", val:"1"},
    {label:"Registered",val:"2"}, 
    {label:"Editor",val:"3"}, 
    {label:"Administrator",val:"4"},
  ],
}
```

Here's a jsBin: http://jsbin.com/xawak/3/

Comment: No luck.  I created a jsbin at [link]http://jsbin.com/xawak/1/[/link].  It doesn't work either, but it would be great if you can tweak it to show me where I'm going wrong.  There seems to be a problem in the {{view}} code, since if you remove it, at least the {{input}} shows up.

Comment: See the jsBin I added to my answer

Comment: Yup, that worked and I was able to incorporate it into my code since I was able to use it to figure out where I'd gone wrong. Thanks for your time, much appreciated.